# Retrieve deleted RDL file from database

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdl

By mistake I deployed wrong version of a RDL file on the ReportServer. This overwrote the existing RDL file (the correct one). Is there any way to retrieve the earlier version of the RDL?

Note: No backup of the database is available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pull it from your source control system. If you aren't using source control, I'd suggest you start.

And start backing up your database (don't forget to backup the transaction log too if you are not in simple recovery mode, don;t want that growing continually until it takes up the whole drive), no excuse for that at all.

Comment: we are already doing source control & backups for the projects on production. This is a one off thing. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever developed the original report may have a client side copy.

"No backup of the database is available."

I assume you are referring to the ReportServer database...